# How to access a parameter of a passed-as-pointer function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a mother function which accepts a function as its pointer. The passed function, accept an integer value X. Inside the mother function, I like to access integer X. How should I do it? The following throws undefined error:

```
bool assign_threads_instructions(void* (* _instr)(int socket_fd) )
{

    int pool_size = get_threads_pool_size();
    for(int i = 0; i < pool_size; i++)
    {
        threads_pool[i] = std::thread(_instr, socket_fd); // here I access the socket_fd parameter throws undefined error
    }
}
```

Comment: `socket_fd` is the name of a parameter to a function whose pointer is passed into here. There is no actual `socket_fd` anywhere. You are confusing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_instr` is the (possible) address of a function which has an `int` argument because `void* (* _instr)(int socket_fd)` declares a pointer named `_instr` which can point to a function returning `void*` and taking a single `int` argument named `socket_fd`. Thus, there is no `socket_fd` variable since you cannot (at least not as simply as through a function pointer) pass a callable packed with arguments.

You could either pass that value in seperately:

```
bool assign_threads_instructions(void* (* _instr)(int), int _fd)
{
    std::size_t pool_size = get_threads_pool_size();
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < pool_size; ++i)
    {
        threads_pool[i] = std::thread(_instr, _fd);
    }
}
```

or have a template `assign_threads_instructions` function that has a to-be-deduced argument and use `std::bind` to generate a callable packed with the desired value.

`std::bind` example:

if you have an assign function template like:

```
template<class F>
void assign_stuff(F&& _f)
{
  std::thread work(_f);
  work.join();
}
```

you can use it to pack callbacks and values together into a single argument via std::bind:

```
void f(int& x)
{
  x = x + 2;
}
int main() 
{
  int q = 55;
  assign_stuff(std::bind(&f, std::ref(q)));
  std::cout << q << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Prints

> 57

Comment: Just while asking here, I was reading some std headers, and had nearly found the solution, and now your answer fully completes that. I respect yours, thank you.

Comment: You should forward the argument when using a forwarding reference.

Comment: @Snps: Indeed, in my example one probably would. In context of OPs usage (passing callable to multiple threads in a loop) I think I wouldn't. Thus, I didn't advertise for it here. But in general I'd rather forward it here.

Answer (score 1):

#### A function pointer is just a function pointer

The declaration of your function `assign_threads_instructions` takes a single parameter: `_instr` wich is of type `void* (*_instr) (int)`, *i.e.*:

> pointer to function taking an `int` and returning pointer to `void`.

The unnecessary naming of the `int` inside the type has no effect other than readability.

Using modern C++ syntax makes this more clear.

```
using callback_t = std::add_pointer_t<void*(int)>;
bool assign_threads_instructions(callback_t instr) { /* ... */ }
```

The obvious answer is that you must pass the value along with the callback to your function.